# Why are the restaurant cars in Hungarian trains closed in Germany?

Tags: trains, germany, food-and-drink, hungary

While on a Hungarian MÁV-START train, I noticed an odd sign saying that due to regulation, the bistro carriage will not be serving food while in Germany. From some googling, it seems that German trains often do have bistro carriages too, so I'm wondering whether this is some temporary rule due to the pandemic or something else?

Comment: The restaurant staff will simply not travel on to Germany but leave in Salzburg or before.

Comment: @Sebastian That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @Sebastian Why though?

Comment: @Sebastian that could be an effect and not the cause "since Hungarian trains cannot serve food in Germany [for X] the train company uses them to man trains going back from Germany, instead of carrying (and paying their salary) while idle".

Comment: From their website it seems that the restaurant cars of **DB** trains only sell food for consumption in the passenger carriage, not for consumption in the restaurant car, and they require the wearing of masks in the sales area. Basically "don't remove the mask while you mingle."

Comment: Because of corona restrictions, the DB restaurant cars only sell food for 'take away', that is, you are not allowed to eat in the restaurant car, but have to take the food to your regular seat and eat there. They are therefore currently using disposable instead of proper tableware as usual. My guess (and therefore not an answer): MÁV is also using proper tableware in their restaurant cars and they are neither willing to spend effort on collecting the tableware from everywhere in the train, nor to introduce disposable tableware just for the short stretches they are serving in Germany.

Comment: I can add some more guesses, VAT issues, different laws regarding food safety or alcohol

Comment: There are actually no Hungarian trains in Germany. When that train is in Germany it is a German, DB operated, train, and thus DB practices and rules apply.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That must've changed in the last couple of weeks as the restaurant car of an ICE I travelled on was very much allowing non-take-away eating at the end of July (and I was allowed to eat my pasta with sauce in the bistro part of the restaurant car as there were no seats in the actual restaurant part left).

Comment: @Jan I have no idea when the rules last changed, but several restrictions have been reintroduced during the last few months. As you probably should know, the number of corona cases is sky-rocketing in Germany as well and the incidence is now 14 times higher than it was by the beginning of July.

Answer (score 5):

In August 2021, it was noticed that the state laws governing the rules for Restaurants, Cafés etc. **excluded** railway dining cars, since they crossed state borders. Therefore the state exceptions/conditions didn't apply to the railway gastronomy.

On the 25th of August 2021 a special federal regulation (CoronaSpWgV) was suggested to correct this situation, afterwhich the general 3-rule would apply. This suggestion was withdrawn and eventuelly the state laws included the railway in their regulations (in Saxony December 2021).

---

> **Corona - Speisewagenverordnung – CoronaSpWgV**
> **Zielsetzung und Notwendigkeit der Regelungen**
> Sofern eine epidemische Lage von nationaler Tragweite durch den Deutschen Bundestag festgestellt wurde, kann gemäß § 28a Absatz 1 Nummer 13 des Infektionsschutzgesetzes der Betrieb von gastronomischen Einrichtungen untersagt oder beschränkt werden. Die Ausführung dieser Bestimmung obliegt den Ländern. Die Länder haben hierzu dementsprechende Regelungen in ihren Coronaschutzverordnungen getroffen. In den Coronaschutzverordnungen der Länder wurden Regelungen getroffen, welche der Gastronomie, d.h. Restaurants, Cafés etc., den Betrieb unter der Erfüllung bestimmter Voraussetzungen ermöglicht. Hiervon werden jedoch nur Betriebe erfasst, welche durch Definition vom Anwendungsbereich des Gaststättengesetzes oder entsprechender Landesgesetze erfasst werden. Gemäß § 25 Absatz 1 Satz 2 des Gaststättengesetzes beziehungsweise entsprechender Vorschriften der Länder sind unter anderem Personenwagen von Eisenbahnunternehmen von der Anwendung des Gaststättengesetzes ausgenommen. **Insofern finden die Bestimmungen der Länder, welche einen Betrieb der Gastronomie ermöglichen, auf Speisewagen keine Anwendung**.
>
> > **Purpose and necessity of the regulation**
> > If an epidemic situation of national importance has been determined by the German Bundestag, the operation of catering facilities can be prohibited or restricted in accordance with Section 28a Paragraph 1 Number 13 of the Infection Protection Act.  The implementation of this provision is the responsibility of the federal states.  The federal states have made corresponding regulations in their corona protection regulations.  In the corona protection ordinances of the federal states, regulations have been made which enable gastronomy, i.e. restaurants, cafés, etc., to operate if certain requirements are met.  However, this only includes businesses that are covered by the definition of the area of ​​application of the Restaurant Act or corresponding state laws.  According to § 25 paragraph 1 sentence 2 of the Restaurant Act or corresponding regulations of the federal states, passenger cars of railway companies are exempt from the application of the Restaurant Act. **In this respect, the regulations of the states that allow catering to operate do not apply to [railway] dining cars**.

---

**Sources**:

- [Verordnung zum Schutz vor Infektionsgefahren in Speisewagen der Eisenbahnen in Bezug auf das Coronavirus SARS-CoV-2 - PDF Free Download](https://docplayer.org/218453434-Verordnung-zum-schutz-vor-infektionsgefahren-in-speisewagen-der-eisenbahnen-in-bezug-auf-das-coronavirus-sars-cov-2.html)